# Can't center <p> nested inside of 2 divs and a section

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center my paragraphs, but having the worst time of trying to do it:

```css
.centerLoginForm {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mainContent {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 1.5% 2.5% 0 2.5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

.underHead,
.underHead p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.underHead {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='centerLoginForm'>
  <section class='mainContent'>
    <h1>Welcome to the BYU Idaho Radio Intranet!</h1>
    <div class='underHead'>
      <p>Computers and computer networks are a funny thing. We interact with them mostly through the internet, which is just a whole bunch of interconnected computers around the world. Well this is an <i>intranet</i>: a local network just like the internet,
        only with fewer connected computers.</p>

      <p>The purpose of this intranet is to guide through troubleshooting, monitoring critical systems, and station documentation. This site is easy to navigate and you should find all the things you are looking for just by following the navigation links.</p>

      <p>This was built to be a living, breathing application. Some dude originally built this, but he welcomes support, ideas, and if somebody wanted to chip in on developing, he would love that too! So please, if you have ideas, thoughts, or skills, share
        them! Engineering unfortunately is having fewer and fewer people enter into its field, and needs as many bright minds as it can take and you have a bright mind!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

As you can see, the text inside of the `<p>` tags is is following it's natural position, instead of following what I have in my class `.underHead`. I've tried `text-align`, `content-align`, `justify-content`, and I just can't figure out a way to center that content.

Comment: erase this line in your .underHead definition then width: 70%; OR if you need it, add margin: 0 auto;

Comment: its already in the center.. you .underHead div has 70% width.. remove the width

Comment: @Kiwad Thank you! I needed to keep the 70% width and your margin: 0 auto; worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking to do:

```css
.centerLoginForm {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mainContent {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 1.5% 2.5% 0 2.5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

.underHead {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='centerLoginForm'>
  <section class='mainContent'>
    <h1>Welcome to the BYU Idaho Radio Intranet!</h1>
    <div class='underHead'>
      <p>Computers and computer networks are a funny thing. We interact with them mostly through the internet, which is just a whole bunch of interconnected computers around the world. Well this is an <i>intranet</i>: a local network just like the internet,
        only with fewer connected computers.</p>

      <p>The purpose of this intranet is to guide through troubleshooting, monitoring critical systems, and station documentation. This site is easy to navigate and you should find all the things you are looking for just by following the navigation links.</p>

      <p>This was built to be a living, breathing application. Some dude originally built this, but he welcomes support, ideas, and if somebody wanted to chip in on developing, he would love that too! So please, if you have ideas, thoughts, or skills, share
        them! Engineering unfortunately is having fewer and fewer people enter into its field, and needs as many bright minds as it can take and you have a bright mind!</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: And what does that do? How does it fix his problem? Don't just blurt out markup!